# javascript function not defined in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have a PHP code as shown below in which at `Line A` popup is created with buttons `Ok` and `Cancel` and message `hello world`.

At Line A, on clicking `Ok` button I am trying to call `secondUser()` function in the javascript below and on clicking `Cancel` button I don't want anything to happen.

```
<?PHP
    // ..... some other code

    if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
        $message = "hello world";
        // create a pop up window with $message on it along with "ok" and "cancel" button
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>if (confirm('$message')) { secondUser(); };</script>";    // Line A
    }

    // ..... some other code
?>
```

I am wondering how I can make a call to `secondUser()` function **(as shown below)** on clicking `Ok` button in the popup. I am getting an error message `secondUser()` function is not defined.

```
<script>
function secondUser () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"login_second_user.php",    //the page containing php script
        type: "post",    //request type,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {registration: "success", name: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"},
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result.abc);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

All my php and js code is in the file [admin.php](https://3v4l.org/eAhTp) In the fiddle, I have mentioned only snippets of code but the basic structure is there.

Comment: If you expect the confirm window to pop up before the page has been sent from the server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming . Otherwise I'm not sure, where the echoed script is actually placed in the DOM tree, as it's really in the wrong place. Both the scripts, the script containing the function, and the script containing the function call, must be in either in `head` or `body`.

Comment: @Teemu I am wondering what wrong I am doing here and if you can give me pointers how I can fix it.

Comment: Just checked it. When the browser parses your page (as it's written on 3v4ll page), the script tag is moved to `head`. There it is parsed and executed before the script containing the function exists. Move the line echoing the script tag to the end of the `body` element.

Comment: @Teemu like this https://3v4l.org/jkBN1 ?

Comment: Yup, that should work.

Comment: @Teemu Unfortunately, Its not working. I reordered the code.

Comment: Please don't use the phrase "_not working_", describe what happens instead.

Comment: I am getting the same error message `secondUser()` not defined.

Comment: Then you're running a cached file or sth ... It's [working](https://jsfiddle.net/bey3prtw/) fine.